# How to Change Default Font Size in iTextSharp After Exporting GridView to PDF?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, gridview, export, itext

I am using the iTextSharp method in the following link to export a GridView to a PDF document:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

The code is like this:

```
protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f,10f,10f,0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();  
}
```

This works perfect except the font size in the PDF. I guess the defaults for iTextSharp are Arial and 12pt.

Is there any way to change this default font and its size (at least its size) globally for the whole PDF?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
iTextSharp.text.Font font20 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont
(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.HELVETICA,20);
```

Comment: Odd that you "can't understand fully" the linked page, yet you've linked to that blog multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed.

(but my initial suggestion isn't it... Font.DEFFAULTSIZE is "static final", so... Derp).

Err... I don't think HTMLWorker's stylesheet code will let you set an overall default font size, thought I haven't worked with it all that much.  I could be wrong.  You can set it by class or tag, but that could be quite a bit of work... hey!

I think you can set the style for "body" which will then affect everything within it.  Unless you're working on HTML fragments, this should do the trick:

```
StyleSheet bodySize = new StyleSheet();
Map<String,String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
props.put(ElementTags.SIZE, "8"); 
bodySize.applyStyle("body", props);

htmlparser.setStyleSheet(bodySize);
```

The way I did it was Change The Source (com.itextpdf.text.Font.java) so that the declaration of `Font.DEFAULTSIZE` was to my liking, but I maintain my own branch... I'm weird like that.

Comment: No, it's Java.  iTextSharp is derived from iText.  You should find it easy to translate.

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.Add(ElementTags.SIZE, "8");
```